# Post request to server. Different responses with different defaultClients

Tags: java, android, http, post

When i try to send post request using Java (JVM on Mac) with correct credentials I got correct response code 302 FOUND.

But when using the same code on the android, with SAME correct params, i got response CODE 200 OK.

Code to send post request:

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(POST_URL);

    List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("auth", "login"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", login));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("set_cookie", "on"));


    httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Comment: Are you getting the same Http Response string?.

Comment: Responses are fully different. 
JVM: HTTP/1.1 302 Found [Server: nginx/1.0.5, Date: Wed, 22 May 2013 07:29:18 GMT, Content-Type: text/html .......
ANDROID: Return only statusLine HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: What are the response urls? They can not be the same. I still thing one of them are being redirected while the other not.

Answer (score 0):

**302 FOUND** is the common way of doing a "redirection", it seems Android or MacJVM is not performing that redirection. Are you using the same SDK version?

Try to use :

```
final HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);
```

Comment: Hello Carlos, problem is not in reddirect, problem is in a different response status. In case then responce code equals 302 server send cookies to client. 
final HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
  HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);
  
  DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  httpclient.setParams(params);
 setRedirecting not solve problem.  Thanks for reply.